# Shortcut with environment variable

Tags: excel, environment-variables, shortcut

I'm at work, with a folder in which we create a daily excel sheet to manage our clients. For the sake of understanding let's imagine this files is in a folder called OCTOBER and they are named MD01, MD02, MD03... based on the day we are.

I was trying to setup a shortcut on my desktop that will call the correct file every time so I don't have to go trough the file structure to access it. Something like this:

```
"....\OCTOBER\MD%DAY%.xls"
```

But the moment I try to setup the path this way I get an error say this is not a valid path. Well, either I am missing something here or what? Can't this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical method is to create a link to a master file in the folder *(say master.xlsm)* The master spreadsheet would automatically:

1. determine the date
2. determine the appropriate file to open
3. open the file *(say MD10.xls)*
4. close itself

Alternatively you could create a little vbscript or powershell script or .bat file to do the same thing.